# Ethers.js - "ERC721A: transfer from incorrect owner" MetaMask Error

Tags: javascript, blockchain, web3js, ethers.js, erc721

My goal is to `setApprovalForAll` for a token contract before executing the `safeTransferFrom` function for each `tokenId` in the NFT collection. This way I will be able to transfer NFTs to another address without MetaMask asking for several approvals.

However I am getting an error upon executing the `safeTransferFrom` function, the following error is triggered:
[image: view image]

This happens even after I have called the `setApprovalForAll` function. The `setApprovalForAll` transaction seems to have also went through successfully:

[image: view MetaMask activity]

but calling `isApprovedForAll` says otherwise (view comment on line 16 in code).

I believe it is possible the error is raised because of me not calling the `setApprovalForAll` function properly, because why else would `isApprovedForAll` return `false`?

```
document.querySelector('.click-me').onclick = async () => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    const signer = await provider.getSigner();

    const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = '0x...';  // token contract address
    const RECEIVER_ADDRESS = '0x...';  // this address expected to get approval for all
    const ABI = [
        'function setApprovalForAll(address operator, bool _approved)',
        'function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)',
        'function isApprovedForAll(address owner, address operator) view returns (bool)'
    ];

    const contract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, ABI, signer);
    try {
        const isApproved = await contract.isApprovedForAll(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, RECEIVER_ADDRESS);
        console.log(isApproved);  // returns false even after several attempts

        await contract.setApprovalForAll(RECEIVER_ADDRESS, true);  // seems to work fine, even shows in MetaMask activity

        // ERROR SEEMS TO OCCUR HERE
        const test = await contract.safeTransferFrom(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, RECEIVER_ADDRESS, 749);  // 749 is my NFT tokenId
        console.log(test);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change contract address to the owner of the NFT see below

```js
document.querySelector('.click-me').onclick = async () => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    const signer = await provider.getSigner();

    const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = '0x...';  // token contract address
    const RECEIVER_ADDRESS = '0x...';  // this address expected to get approval for all
    const ABI = [
        'function setApprovalForAll(address operator, bool _approved)',
        'function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)',
        'function isApprovedForAll(address owner, address operator) view returns (bool)'
    ];

    const contract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, ABI, signer);
    try {
        const isApproved = await contract.isApprovedForAll(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, RECEIVER_ADDRESS);
        console.log(isApproved);  // returns false even after several attempts

        await contract.setApprovalForAll(RECEIVER_ADDRESS, true);  // seems to work fine, even shows in MetaMask activity

        // FIXED
        const test = await contract.safeTransferFrom(signer.address, RECEIVER_ADDRESS, 749);  // 749 is my NFT tokenId
        console.log(test);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }    
};
```